# How would I texture this track correctly?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

So I'm creating a model of the nurburgring for an animation I want to make. I have created the track and its modeled how I like it. However, im not sure how to texture it. I want it to look something similar to this:[image: Reference picture.]

Dont mind the actual terrain, that will be for another question. I just would like a way to get a realistic road texture. I have a semi realistic texture picked from [poliigon.com](https://www.poliigon.com/). Here is what it looks like:[image: This is the texture im working with.]It has all the extra data with it too like bump mapping, etc.. I have the image applied to the track and this is what I currently have:[image]
As you can see it has been applied and is applied semi correctly (I think). Now my thing is I just want to make it look a bit more realistic. I created this track by taking a square, expanding it and stretching it around a bezier curve through the array and curve modifiers. If there is any way to just make it  little bit more realistic, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: The texture you choose it's a close up of the road, while the picture you are showing its a road in a totally different scale. What kind of show are you planning to animate?

Comment: Pretty much just a "time trial" in which its an f1 car going around the nurburgring, it will go around for the lap and at SOME point it will loose control and wreck.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to wrie "shots", not "show"... will the camera near to the road, far away, both...?

Comment: It will be both. There will be far shots and close shots, some from overheads, some from pretty much on the ground

Comment: Could I possibly gather a few more similar textures and have them randomly place along the track to make it a bit more randomly realistic?